# mysqli query generates 500 internal server error

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$mysql_connection = new mysqli(blah blah blah..
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $mysql_connection->query($query);
```

That little last instruction here generates a 500 Internal Server Error in my site, I didn't posted the whole code because I didn't want to make you stay hours to read it.
I tested it by printing something after every instruction that may have caused the error, and when it reaches the query part, id stops.

I'm a very beginner in PHP, so sorry if it's a dumb question.

So, any little hint will be very appreciated.

Comment: Check the server's error log. It'll have details about the 500 error that do not get shown in the usual browser page - 500 errors usually contain internal server details that should NOT be allowed to leak out to end users, so by default what you see in the browser is useless for debugging.

Comment: it doesn't help too much just knowing its a 500 internal server error. Obviously you did something wrong in your backend setup. Maybe you should give us a bit more of your code? Kind of hard to help just looking at what you provided.  Are you sure that your mysqli connection was properly made?

Comment: I am sure, if I delete this instruction, everything works great, I verified the connection with errrno and it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the connection is not going through for some reason 
can you add this to your code and post the output

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the error log. there should be some more info as to why it's failing. if still unable to fix problem, post the error log entry here so we can help you

Comment: Uhm, I uploaded this to a Linux Server (previously was on IIS) and here's what i get: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/content/82/8396182/html/new_ver/trash/functions.php on line 34. Now, as fac as I know, if I create a new mysqli(...) instance in $mysql_connecton let's say, $mysql_connection is actually an object, isn't id?

Comment: should you be newing up the mysqli thing? I believe you should just call mysqli_connect(..,...,...) which will return you a valid connection object, on which you should then be able to invoke the query method. I am not currently in PHP, but from what I remember you don't do `new mysqli()`